# Fusion table query using variable?

Tags: google-maps-api

I am new to google map api as well as fusion table. I want to make a dynamic query using fusion table. for that i am using the following piece of code:

```
var layer3
var yr = 2015;
layer3 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
          query: {

            select: 'Name_Farmer',
            from: '19ZEAwp0-rJNI1alzTRzgjJBqT1SKR3Ij_N_LfAxR',
             where: 'Year > 2015'
// where: 'Year > yr'
          }
        });

    layer3.setMap(map);
```

If the where clause 'year>2015' works, then why is 'year>yr' not working when I have assigned a global variable for `yr=2015`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are assigning a string object to a dictionary element, `where`. Everything within the quotation marks are considered as literal, i.e., if yr is within the quotes, it gets assigned literally, as in your Year >2015 case. Therefore you need to format your string properly before assigning. I think, `where: 'Year > ' + yr` should work.